# Print info stored in a list of classes to console

Tags: c#, console

I am a C# beginner, and i am trying to learn the fundamentals of coding in general as i am new to it. I have been watching some tutorials and decided to start writing a simple code, and improve/add more abilities as i learn more.

Currently i am creating a simple database, where i can store some information about people. I decided to try to use classes for that and had problem with printing the data i stored in the list.

I tried `Console.WriteLine(people.ToString());` and it didn't work.

I tried to incorporate `string.Join(delimiter, list.Select(i => i.Boo).ToArray())` which i found on another post, but failed to do so.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        Console.Write("How many people are to be stored?: ");

        int personCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i=1; i<=personCount; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Name of person "+ i + ":");
            string nameInput=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Age of "+ nameInput +": ");
            int ageInput= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Height of " + nameInput + ": ");
            double heightInput = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine());
            people.Add(new Person(nameInput, ageInput, heightInput));
        }

        // here goes (i think) the code to type info stored in list

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public double height;

    public Person(string name, int age, double height)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

I wanted to have a list of info, instead i get only the following:

`System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Studies.Person]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to override the `ToString` method in the `Person` class and handle the output there

Comment: If you want People.ToString() to be nice looking,  you should override it. Try add new method not People class like: public override string ToString() { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", name, age, height); }

Comment: @MongZhu can you explain a little bit? And wow you guys are fast! :)

Comment: I wouldn't use a class for this, I'd use a DataTable.  You've got quite a bit more flexibility with a DataTable when it comes to this kind of thing.  You can do bulk inserts into your back-end database, output to Excel, .csv, etc with ease, search, filter, sort, etc.  Lots more fun stuff that comes pretty easily with a DataTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to override the [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) method in the `Person` class and handle the output there.

The Object.ToString method returns:

> A string that represents the current object.

This is basically a string representation of your object (Person). By default it will return the full classname including the namespace. When you pass an object like a person to `Console.WriteLine` (which expects a `string` as parameter) it will call automatically the `ToString` method which every object in the framework inherits from `Object`. This should explain your output:

> System.Collections.Generic.List

when you used `Console.WriteLine(people.ToString());`. It called the `ToString` method that `List` inherits from `Object` and printed the full name.

If you override it in your class it will take your version and you can determine how the output is supposed to look like

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public double height;

    public Person(string name, int age, double height)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name: {name} Age: {age} Height: {height}";
    }
}
```

now you can use `string.Join`

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, people));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the default implementation of `ToString()`, inherited from `object` (the root of every inheritance hierarchy), is to print the type name. To make it work, you must override `ToString()` and let it do something useful

E.g., in class person write

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Person {name}, aged by (age}, height = {height}";
}
```

Note that this method is already overridden in other types like `int`, `double` or `DateTime`. But since the system does not know how a meaningful string representation of a person (or any other user-defined type) should look like, it doesn't provide such an override.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- You're calling .ToString() on the list, not the individual Person
  objects in your list. So what you're telling the machine is to "Tell 
  me about this list not the objects inside of it" to which it is
  replying"This is a List of Person objects".
- Your Person class doesn't have a .ToString() method override, so when
  you call .ToString().

So you need a .ToString() method override in your Person class as well as to iterate through the list and call .ToString() for each Person object.